# TypeScript class didn't recognize inside Angular Controller Class Constructor

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am having issue creating property for my model class inside my angular controller through constructor. Here is my code looks like

**app.ts**

```
    module app {
        angular
            .module("formApp", [
                "ngMaterial",
                "ngMdIcons",
                "ngMessages"
            ]);
    }
```

**model.ts**

```
module app.model {
    export interface IPatient {
        firstName: string;
        lastName: string;
        gender: string;
        birthDate: Date;
        currentMedications: string;
        notes: string;
        isMedicare: boolean;
        medicareName: string;
        medications: string[];
        ethnicity: string[];
    }
    export class Patient implements IPatient {

        constructor(
            public firstName: string,
            public lastName: string,
            public gender: string,
            public birthDate: Date,
            public currentMedications: string,
            public notes: string,
            public isMedicare: boolean,
            public medicareName: string,
            public medications: string[],
            public ethnicity: string[]
        ) {

        }
    }
}
```

**controller.ts**

```
module app.main {

        class MainController {

            constructor(public patient: app.model.IPatient) {

            }
        }

        angular
            .module("formApp")
            .controller("MainController", MainController);
    }
```

I am trying to create patient property through constructor. But I am getting this error when my app run

[image]

Comment: replace screenshorts with actual text

Comment: Your error message is complaining about a productProvider so I think you need to resolve that first.

Comment: Sorry, that screenshot is not correct. I just updated that.

Comment: It's actually looking at the property name in constructor and throws error message like if I write `public product: app.model.IPatient` then it says `productProvider` not injected.

Answer (score 0):

You must do a import in the main-controller of the app.model

PD: I suggest a Folders-by-Feature Structure , and review every import and export

Comment: Didn't work either. It's just to make shortcut for long namespace since I am not using AMD. isn't it?

Comment: I had reestructured a angular app from ES5 to ES6  using this guide [link ](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#migrating-to-typescript),follow the example there. It's a good thing folow this Angular 1 preparation guide.